# vtable in case of virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

What is the use of vtable (or why is vtable required ) in case of virtual inheritance ? what does this vtable points to in this case.

example:

```
class A
{
    void show()
    { }
};

class B : virtual A
{
    void disp()
    { }
};
```

In the above example the size of class B is 8 bytes. which means class B has vptr pointing to a Vtable. What does this vtable point to .

Comment: The C++ standard has nothing to say on the subject of vtables. As such, these notions are compiler-specific. Which compiler(s) have you tried this on?

Comment: GCC and Clang use it for typeinfo.

Comment: A vtable consists of pointers to functions, so what it points to is blocks of machine code, basically.

Comment: @melpomene, what OP is actually asking is: in the case of normal inheritance without any virtual functions, most compilers don't bother with a vtable. In this scenario, there are no virtual functions, yet there still is a vtable which is weird to him.

Comment: @Frank , Yes thats exactly my question. I have read that these vtable points to subobject of class A. Is that true?

Comment: The vtable doesn't do much for a single class like this, but when you inherit from several classes all deriving from `A` they will need a way to find the single instance of their shared base class.

Answer (score 0):

A vtable is the most common way of implementing the `virtual` keyword in C++ -- any class that uses the `virtual` keyword will have a vtable created for it and every instance of that class will contain a pointer to that (single) vtable.  The vtable contains information on the dynamic class of the object (to support `dynamic_cast` and `typeinfo`) as well as information as to where virtual base classes and functions of the class are located.

In this specific case, the vtable for `B` will likely contain just dynamic class info, as `A` has no data members or virtual functions.

Comment: Note that you can only use `dynamic_cast` and `typeinfo` on polymorphic classes, not on classes with virtual bases like `B`, even though the underlying mechanism is fully present for such classes on many (but not all) compilers.